# Handling Spinner initialization and onItemSelected callback

Tags: android, listview, initialization, spinner

I used to dynamically populate a Table Layout with different elements per row, among them a Spinner.
To handle the initialization of spinner values i used what most recommended: a boolean flag variable. The code went something like this

```
public class spinnerHandling implements OnItemSelectedListener{

   public void dynamicallyPopulateTableLayout(int a){
      ...
      //initialize spinner with default values
      mySpinner.setSelection(a);       

      mySpinner.setTag(true);
      mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
      ...
   }

  @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
           long id) {
      if(!(Boolean)parent.getTag()){
         //my code
         ...
      }
      parent.setTag(false);
   }
}
```

This worked fine.
Later i decided that i should use a List View instead of a Table Layout. For that i have a custom ArrayAdapter that uses a row Layout, in which of course i have a Spinner, to populate the List View. As those of you who are familiar with List Views, understand its complex dynamic behavior, would know that the somehow static turn around of the boolean flag method wont work.
After three days of tremendous headache trying to find a way to resolve this issue, i just came across the spinner's isDirty() method that in contrast with isPressed(), isSelected(), etc. actually changes its boolean values when spinner item is selected by user.
the code is something like this:

```
public class spinnerHandling implements OnItemSelectedListener{
     public void dynamicallyPopulateListView(int a){
      ...

      //initialize spinner with default values
      mySpinner.setSelection(a);  
      mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
      ...
   }

  @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
           long id) {
      if(!parent.isDirty()){
         //my code
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

This seems to work fine!
But i would like to make sure that isDirty() handles properly spinner initialization and user selection.
Can you please confirm or contradict this behavior?
Thank you.

Comment: After some research and tests, i can confirm that isDirty() does not work as i assumed and described above.